# What is the purpose of `returningItems` in `NSExtensionContext.completeRequest`?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on a standard Action Extension in my iOS app and the Xcode template contains the lines:

```
@IBAction func done() {
    // Return any edited content to the host app.
    // This template doesn't do anything, so we just echo the passed in items.
    self.extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: self.extensionContext!.inputItems, completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Here is the **[documentation for `completeRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsextensioncontext/1411301-completerequest)**.

#### Questions

- What is the purpose of passing `returningItems` to `completeRequest`?
- Do apps actually receive edited content from an action extension?
- If yes, where can I find the API on the receiving end?
- What are the consequences for me to pass an empty array?

Answer (score 2):

I made small [research](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52823399/4322841) for other question, that may be found helpful here.

Shortly:

There is callback in `UIActivityViewController` with parameter:

> returnedItems - An array of NSExtensionItem objects containing any modified data. Use the items in this array to get any changes made to the original data by an extension