# Where does a host app handle NSExtensionContext#completeRequest?

Tags: ios, ios-app-extension, replaykit

When you call `completeRequest(returningItems:completionHandler:)` from an extension, where does this get handled by the host app?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: *did not checked my assumptions*, but may be this helps.

1) [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Share.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH12-SW1) states:

> Call the completeRequestReturningItems:completionHandler: method,
>   which signals the host app that its original request is complete

2) [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW2) - Figure 2-3 shows that "Host"-app - is app that starts some work with extension. For example, "Host" may be the app in which user touches "Share"-button. Then this "Host"-app sends some data (which user wants to share) to extension.

3) "Sharing data"-extension, I think, very common example of extension. So very probable that somewhere in `UIActivityViewController` must be way to realise `completeRequest(returningItems:completionHandler:)` that you looking for and that called from extension.
And this is what I found:

```
@property(nullable, nonatomic, copy) UIActivityViewControllerCompletionWithItemsHandler completionWithItemsHandler NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0); // set to nil after call
```

[documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityviewcontroller/completionwithitemshandler) says about this property:

> Upon the completion of an activity, or the dismissal of the activity view controller, the view controller’s completion block is executed.

and:

> returnedItems - 
>   An array of NSExtensionItem objects containing any modified data. Use the items in this array to get any changes made to the original data by an extension

Again, I **did not test it**. But this property looks like handler you looks for.

Comment: Ah ok so maybe it's only used in the case that your extension uses a share sheet?

Comment: I would say: seems `returnedItems` are used by host app in case that your extension launched by host app via share sheet. 
Is this case _only_ or there are some other cases - I don't know. 
Apple [describes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/) about 19 extension types for iOS. May be extension launching classes for extensions of some other types have callbacks for `returnedItems` too.